# Stored codes on 2004 sl500

Tags: transmission, mercedes-benz, sl500

Purchased vehicle in January had a diagnostic done on it by a certified Mercedes mechanic. Had one major code come back only one which the dealership fixed. Not even three months after purchase two major codes have popped up labeled as stored having to do with the transmission. My question is can we tell when the stored code first appeared and when it was cleared. It’s my understanding that these codes would have shown themselves previously but had been cleared and have resurfaced because the issue was not dealt with.  I’m hoping to prove the dealership erased the codes in order to sell it.  Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no date stamp stored with any codes in the ECU. If the codes existed prior, but were wiped, there's no way to know. The only thing you can know for sure is, if there were codes when your MB mechanic looked at it, it seems he would have told you about them. This means, these are fresh codes. There is no way for you to try and pin it back onto the dealership, at least not looking at it through the codes.